# Why doesn't the isolate receive the stop message?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

The UI shows two button: One button to start an isolate, and a second button to stop it at next occasion.
The UI (widget) code looks like this:

```
SendPort sendToIsolatePort;

void _onStartIsolateButtonPushed() async {
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  receivePort.listen(onMessageReceivedFromIsolate);
  Isolate.spawn(runAsIsolate, receivePort.sendPort);
}

void _onStopIsolateButtonPushed() async {
  sendToIsolatePort.send("Stop");
}

void onMessageReceivedFromIsolate(var message) {
  if (message is String) {
    print("Message received from isolate: " + message);
  } else if (message is SendPort) {
    print("Reply port received");
    sendToIsolatePort = message;
    sendToIsolatePort.send("Hello World?!?");
  }
}
```

The code in isolate.dart looks like this:
(Note: this one's not in a widget or class, just some global functions)

```
import 'dart:isolate';

SendPort sendPort;
bool isRunning;

void runAsIsolate(SendPort port) async {
  sendPort = port;
  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  receivePort.listen(onIsolateMessageReceived);

  isRunning = true;
  sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

  while (isRunning) {
    _doSomething();
    _doSomethingMore();
  }

  receivePort.close();
  sendPort.send("Stopped");
  print("Leaving isolate...");
}

void onIsolateMessageReceived(var message) {
  if (message is String) {
    print("Isolate: messate received: " + message);
    if (message == "Stop") {
      isRunning = false;
    }
  } else {
    print("WTFlutter... " + message.toString());
  }
}

void _doSomething() {}
void _doSomethingMore() {}
```

Now, for some reason, the isolate neither receives the "Hello World?!?" nor the "Stop" message. Do you have any ideas why? And how to fix it?

Also: Is there a simpler (or shorter) way of executing a thread in flutter? The isolate approach, and it's stream communication, appear very much over-complicated for something as common as parallel execution.

Your advise is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: as for executing a thread: no, there is nothing else. isolates are the fundamental building blocks in flutter, and that is the design - no shared memory.

Comment: try to add a `else` clause and print something, in your `onMessageReceivedFromIsolate` to debug

Comment: have a look at: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html , which is a easier way to do computations in another "thread"(isolate)

Comment: @ch271828n Thanks for your help! Communication from the isolate up to the widget works fine (the reply port (`sendToIsolatePort`) is delivered through `onMessageReceivedFromIsolate()` ). The problem happens when sending from the widget down to the isolate: `sendToIsolatePort.send()` seems to be executed (at the widget), but `onIsolateMessageReceived()` isn't called (at the isolate). In other words: The messages don't arrive at the isolate. Pretty complicated...

Comment: I see a problem: your `while (isRunning)` will consume all time in our main isolate. thus there is no time that your `onIsolateMessageReceived` can be called! Try to remove your while loop, and do this instead: `while(isRunning) await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));`

Comment: @ch271828n Yes! That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Since this is the answer that solves your question, I rephrase it into an answer below. If you find it helpful you can vote up and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Rephrased from the comments above, since this is the answer that solves the question.)

I see a problem: your `while (isRunning)` will consume all time in our main isolate. thus there is no time that your `onIsolateMessageReceived` can be called! Try to remove your while loop, and do this instead: `while(isRunning) await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));`.

As for executing a thread: No, there is nothing else. isolates are the fundamental building blocks in flutter, and that is the design - no shared memory. However, there do exist some small shortcuts. For example, have a look at: api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html , which is a easier way to do computations in another "thread"(isolate).